# Warning: gzuncompress() Error

Tags: magento, caching, gzip

I am using the [this caching extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zoom-full-page-cache-1742.html) for Magento:

The problem is that every now and again the home page will just get returned as a blank page.  When I check the logs I have this error:

> `2013-04-14T10:44:23+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: gzuncompress() [<a href='function.gzuncompress'>function.gzuncompress</a>]: data error  in /public_html/app/code/local/Ezapps/Zoom/Helper/Data.php on line 499`

This is the code the error is referring to:

```
public function decompress($ajax_state) {
    return gzuncompress(stripslashes(base64_decode($ajax_state)));      
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: what is on /public_html/app/code/local/Ezapps/Zoom/Helper/Data.php on line 499?

Comment: Most probably you either got invalid `base64` or invalid `gz` data (or the uncompressed data is a bomb, i.e. 32K times bigger than the compressed one). I'd start with checking whether `$ajax_state` contains valid `base64` data and continue from there.

Comment: Line 499 is the second code snippet in my initial post ie.  return gzuncompress(stripslashes(base64_decode($ajax_state)));